# Парсинг сайтов на GRAB с использованием скролла (python)

Tags: python, парсер, grab

Есть парсер на python+grab, который берет однотипные данные из некой "таблицы" на сайте, которая прогружает значения во время скролла. Есть ли возможность реализации скролла,используя grab? На данный момент парсер берет лишь первые значения из таблицы, которые прогружаются сразу

Comment: А значения, которые подгружаются в таблицу подгружаются через ajax? Если да, то имеет смысл парсить ответ скрипта, который запрашивается через ajax.

Answer (score 0):

посмотри решение в selenium-webdriver framework, для python,

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```